# Scanning with MpCmdRun.exe as local system does not generate events in event viewer

Tags: windows

I need to run a scan script using MpCmdRun.exe -Scan -ScanType 3 -File "some\path\here".

If I run it as my user (elevated or not), it will generate an event log for "scan started" and another for "scan finished" in event viewer under "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Operational"

Problem is, if I run it as local system, the scan itself will work fine, but I get no entries in event viewer. And I do rely on event viewer to check scan statistics.
(somehow on scantype 1 it works)

Does anybody know if there's a way to get the scan logs for a system user?
Also checked the MpCmdScan.log, but that's only in the user's folder.

(Windows 10 and 11)